# How to auto increment Map's key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Map which I am using to add successCount as key and List as value to capture failed ones.
Say if I call processRequest() 5 times then requestCount will be 5 and successCount will be sum of all the success ones.

I see successCount will always be 1 when I tried. Please advice how can I achieve this, thanks

```
  public updateCust() {
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> responseMap = new HashMap<>();

    int requestCount = 0;
    int successCount = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Tuple>> entry : custsGb.entrySet()) {
        processRequest(responseMap, failedIds);
        requestCount++;
    }

    if (requestCount == responseMap.keySet().stream().findFirst().get().intValue()) {
         // all success - 200
    } 
 }


public HashMap<Integer, List<String>> processRequest(HashMap<Integer, List<String>> responseMap, List<String> failedIds) {
    int successCount = 0;
    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
         responseMap.put(successCount++, failedIds);
    } else {
         failedIds.add(id);
     responseMap.put(successCount, failedIds);
    }
    return responseMap;
}
```

Comment: Doing what you describe is ill advised.  What happens if the key count is identical to another key count?  Why not reverse roles of  key and value?   If the `failedIds` is unique, why not sum the successes  (value) for each failedIds (key)? It would help if you would provide an example of how you expect the map will evolve over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do something like this. This will increment the successes for each `failedId`.  Of course failedId and successes seems a bit confusing. So instead of summing successes you would be summing failures. Note that `merge` will either initalize the value to `1` for key if it is not present, or increment the value by `1` if it is.

```
Map<String, Integer> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
      responseMap.merge(failedIds, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Or create a map of maps.  The inner map will hold the `successes and failures` for each `Id`.

Here is how that might look using `Random` to generate possible values for `id`, and `status`.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
String status;
String id;
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    id = "ID" + (r.nextInt(3) + 1); // id from 1 to 3
    status = r.nextBoolean() ? "SUCCESSES" : "FAILURES";  
    responseMap.computeIfAbsent(id, v -> new HashMap<>()).merge(status,
            1, Integer::sum);
}

responseMap.entrySet().forEach(e1->{
     System.out.println(e1.getKey());
     e1.getValue().entrySet().forEach(e2-> {
         System.out.println("   " + e2);
     });
});
```

prints something like

```
ID2
   FAILURES=7
   SUCCESSES=6
ID1
   FAILURES=6
   SUCCESSES=2
ID3
   FAILURES=6
   SUCCESSES=3
```

First the inner map is created if it doesn't exist for the given id.  In any event `computeIfAbsent` returns the value which will be a `Map<String, Integer>`.  Then `merge` is like before where the counts are incremented for the status of the call, use `Random.nextBoolean()` to assign whether th current status is a success (true) or failure (false);